# puppetdb not starting up

Tags: puppet, startup

Getting the error below from log file, Any idea why this is not working.

```
2015-02-06 13:09:48,212 ERROR [utils.logging] Uncaught exception
org.ini4j.InvalidFileFormatException: parse error (at line: 61): You have new mail in /var/mail/root
        at org.ini4j.spi.AbstractParser.parseError(AbstractParser.java:53)
        at org.ini4j.spi.AbstractParser.parseOptionLine(AbstractParser.java:85)
        at org.ini4j.spi.IniParser.parse(IniParser.java:101)
        at org.ini4j.spi.IniParser.parse(IniParser.java:62)
        at org.ini4j.Ini.load(Ini.java:109)
        at org.ini4j.Ini.<init>(Ini.java:50)
        at puppetlabs.kitchensink.core$ini_to_map.invoke(core.clj:384)
        at clojure.core$map$fn__4207.invoke(core.clj:2487)
        at clojure.lang.LazySeq.sval(LazySeq.java:42)
        at clojure.lang.LazySeq.seq(LazySeq.java:60)
        at clojure.lang.Cons.next(Cons.java:39)
        at clojure.lang.RT.boundedLength(RT.java:1654)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:130)
        at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:617)
        at puppetlabs.kitchensink.core$inis_to_map.invoke(core.clj:411)
        at puppetlabs.kitchensink.core$inis_to_map.invoke(core.clj:402)
        at com.puppetlabs.puppetdb.config$parse_config.invoke(config.clj:415)
        at com.puppetlabs.puppetdb.cli.services$_main.doInvoke(services.clj:237)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:421)
        at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:419)
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:163)
        at clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:532)
        at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:617)
        at com.puppetlabs.puppetdb.core$run_command.invoke(core.clj:87)
        at com.puppetlabs.puppetdb.core$_main.doInvoke(core.clj:95)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
        at com.puppetlabs.puppetdb.core.main(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an error in your `ini` file. Check line 61.

Comment: It looks that it was maybe a package version issue, once I reverted back to older version , it worked fine.